# Probability that the first marble was blue, given the second is blue

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are 3 blue, 4 green, 5 red marbles in a bag. A marble is chosen at random, if the marble is blue or green it is set aside. If it is red, it is placed back in the bag. What is the probability, that the first marble was blue, given the second marble chosen was also blue?
Dont get how knowing the second marble chosen helps me find the odds of the first marble being blue

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$B_i,R_i,G_i$$
represent events of the marble of the color starting with the same letter being chosen in the $i$-th attempt.

By [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) we have

$$P(B_1|B_2)=\frac{P(B_1\cap B_2)}{P(B_2)}$$
And by [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)
$$P(B_2)=P(B_2\cap B_1)+P(B_2\cap G_1)+P(B_2\cap R_1)$$
Thus
$$P(B_2)=\frac{3}{12}\frac{2}{11}+\frac{4}{12}\frac{3}{11}+\frac{5}{12}\frac{3}{12}$$

Probability of the first marbel being blue is
$$P(B_1)=\frac{1}{4}$$
Probability of the secod marbel being blue, given the first one was blue is
$$P(B_2|B_1)=\frac{2}{11}$$

$$P(B_1\cap B_2)=P(B_2|B_1)P(B_1)=\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$$

Finally concluding

$$P(B_1|B_2)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{11}}{\frac{3}{12}\frac{2}{11}+\frac{4}{12}\frac{3}{11}+\frac{5}{12}\frac{3}{12}}$$

Comment: That can't be right: $P(B_2)$ is much too large. In particular, you have $P(B_2\cap B_1) = \frac{2}{11}$ but $P(B_1\cap B_2) = \frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$ $-$ these can't both be right.

Comment: Thank you, I made a careless mistake. I have edited the text.

Comment: Better! But $P(B_2\cap R_1)$ is wrong, because the red ball is replaced in the bag.

Comment: Thank you, I see I completely misread the question first time around. I have made the edits.

Comment: +1 for reaching what looks to be the right answer! But it is needlessly complicated: you don't need to calculate $P(B_1\cap B_2)$, because it is the same as $P(B_2\cap B_1)$, which you already know.

Comment: I tried to be as explicit as possible, as to reveal how Bayes and total probability interact. Perhaps I made it less understandable, instead of more. Will abide to simplicity the next time I answer a question.